# Rebuild select2 options without losing current selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown element in my application that gets filtered based on user input.

To perform the filtering, I do the following:

```
$mySelect2Menu.empty();
$.each(newData, function(ind, val) {
   $mySelect2Menu.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', val).text(val));
});
```

As a consequence of this, however, subsequent calls to `$('#mySelect2Menu').val()` will return null.

I'd like to be able to keep any selected values in the select2 after the menu options are repopulated.  What's the best way to go about doing this?

As an important side note, for my particular use case, there is a guarantee that when the menu is repopulated, the user's current selection **will** be available in `newData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this in a pretty simple way.  I just store the currently selected options in a temporary variable, rebuild the select, and then call `select2('val')` with the temporary variable:

```
var selectedVals = $sel.val();
$sel.empty();
$.each(newOptions, function(ind, val) {
  $sel.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', val).text(val));
});
$sel.select2('val', selectedVals);
```